# scroll hacia abajo con javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll

quiero hacer el efecto scroll automatico en javascrip pero no sé en que me esta fallando.

En si el boton se posiciona en un mapa diseñado en openlayer y quiero que al presionar el boton me lleve al fondo de la pagina o al div proximos-horarios.
Presioné el boton y llama a la función como corresponde ya que le inserte un alert para berificar que ésto realmente fuera así.

Este es mi codigo html y la parte de javascript en donde creo y ejecuto el botón.

```js
 var botonscroll = document.createElement('botonscroll');
    botonscroll.innerHTML="<img src='img/horarios_bus.png'/>";
    var elementoDivboton = document.createElement('divscroll');
    elementoDivboton.className = 'boton-scroll';
   // elementoDivboton.onclick =scroll() ;
    elementoDivboton.appendChild(botonscroll);
    
    var NuevoControlBotonScroll = new ol.control.Control({ element:elementoDivboton });
map.addControl(NuevoControlBotonScroll);
//elementoDivImagen.style.display = 'none';
 
  $('.boton-scroll').bind("click", function () {
  alert ('ingreso');
//       var dest = $("proximos_horarios").offset().top;
//       $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: dest},600);


  $('a[href*="#horarios"]').on('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault()

     $('html, body').animate(
         {
             scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top,
         },
         500,
         'linear'
     )
 })
 $(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
         $('a.scroll-top').fadeIn('slow');
     } else {
         $('a.scroll-top').fadeOut('slow');
     }
 });
 $('a.scroll-top').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600);
 });




  
  });
```

```css
.boton-scroll {
   border-radius: 22px;
   top: 90%;
    right: 27px;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 16px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58);
    cursor: pointer
  }
```

```html
  <div  data-role="main" id="headerlineas" style="height:100%;width:100%; position:absolute; background:#FFF; " >
 
   


    <div align="center" id="map" class="map" style="height:80%;width:100%; background:#DADADA;">
    
 
  

   <div style="width:99%;">
    <select id="cuadras" style="width:100%; background:#DADADA;"></select>
    
    </div> 

 
   
   <?php echo mapalinea($_GET[a]);?> 
  
 <div id="snackbar">No se encontraron Resultados para esta consulta, Por favor intente de nuevo</div>
 


</div>
<div id="proximos_horarios" style="visibility: block; width: 100%;">

 <a id="titulo_horario_proximo_origen" href="#"
  style="background-color: #86CE18; color: #FFF; width: 100%; font-size: 12px; scroll-behavior: smooth;"></a><br>



 <a id="horario_proximo_origen" href="#"
  style="color: #82867d; font-size: larger; font-family: unset;"></a> <br>
 <br> <a id="titulo_horario_proximo_destino_transbordo" href="#horarios"
  style="visibility: hidden; background-color: #01BFFF; color: #FFF; width: 100%; font-size: 12px; scroll-behavior: smooth;"></a><br>

 <a id="horario_proximo_destino_transbordo" href="#"
  style="visibility: hidden; color: #82867d; font-size: larger; font-family: unset;"></a>
 <br>
 <br>
</div>

 
</body ">
```

Comment: Si no te molesta que no funciona en IE y Safari puedes utilizar [scroll-behavior: smooth](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior). Que no funciona significa que el scroll no será `smooth`

Answer (score 1):

yo utilizo esta funcion

```html
$('a[href*="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    $('html, body').animate(
        {
            scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top,
        },
        500,
        'linear'
    )
})
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
        $('a.scroll-top').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $('a.scroll-top').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
$('a.scroll-top').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600);
});
```

y luego simplemente en el enlace pongo el href al div

`<li><a href="#horarios">Horario</a></li>`

Comment: Lo probe amigo y no me lo está tomando. Se me queda plantado donde estaba nomas.

Comment: ahi edite el codigo, estará bien asi? puse el href en el id="titulo_horario_proximo_destino_transbordo"

Comment: no, la funcion tienes que quitar "horarios" y dejar solo "#" para que se ejecute en todos los href que tengan "#" y luego donde quieras que te lleve tienes que ponerle el id, osea que quieres que te lleve a el div juanito "<div  id=juanito>", desde donde quieres que vaya le pones el "href=#juanito"